# How to add Like Button to Joomla Module through editor

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, joomla1.5

I would like to add the 'like' button to a module that will be in the left side of the page.  When I add the code that Facebook supplies, Joomla will not save the JavaScript.  It only saves the div and code before and after.  What am I missing?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
  <script>
    (function(d){
              te var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
              if (d.getElementById(id)) 
                {return;} 
              js = d.createElement('script'); 
              js.id = id; 
              js.async = true; 
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"; 
              d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js); 
              }
              (document)
    );
  </script> 
  <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="facebook.com/platform"; data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div`>.
```

Let me try this again. When I enter the html and then save the module, I loose everything from the `<script>` to the `</script>` tag

Comment: Can you please post the whole code?

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;.   When I save the html in a module or an article, I loose everything between the <script> and the </script> tags.
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>.  Let me try this again.  When I enter the html and then save the module, I loose everything from the <script> to the </script> tags

Comment: @Bob you can edit your question at any time by pressing the edit link. Also you can format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K I did both for you. I hope I got it right

Comment: Thank you for the help formatting my code for the question.  I am still having trouble with the code.  When I paste the provided code into a Joomla article or module, all of the code between the script tags disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Global Configuration -> turn off the editor -> save settings.

Create your module, paste the code and save.  When you edit that module in the future be sure to turn the editor off again.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor is filtering your script tags. The easiest solution I found was to install a plugin such as Sourcerer to allow insertion of code (PHP, CSS, JavaScript) directly in to any Joomla article.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/5051